# Scroll Bar Hiding and Unhiding on pages load

Tags: javascript, html, css

I Tried to find some topic about this issue but i haven't found..

I have a problem on my website, when loading my pages, the scroll bar get hide and unhide just for 1 second that causes content to shift fast..

Yes, i already have tried this code, and i'm using it now:

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

However the problem still there. This problem occours on the latest version of google chrome.

I have a live example if someone want to see, just switch to home -> episodios page:
[Live site](https://animesonline.fan)

I apretiate your help!

Comment: Hard understand your problem and the web you give seems working (maybe i miss something?)

Comment: Maybe try `scrollbar-gutter: stable`

Comment: @ZachJensz The shift has been fixed however the scroll bar still hiding and unhiding.. have some way to avoid it?

Comment: yes, scrollbar-gutter: stable

Comment: @ZachJensz I already used it, but still hiding.. check: https://superanimesonline.net/episodios2.php

Comment: I'm getting some really weird flashes, unstyled content at certain widths, and lots of weird scrollbars. Too much work to help you fix. Take Kevin Powell's [conquering-responsive-layouts](https://courses.kevinpowell.co/conquering-responsive-layouts).

Comment: Could you give me a screen shot?